# Parity: Function in derived contract not working

Tags: solidity, parity

Working with the Parity client and web3 Javascript API on a private chain, I tested the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract simple {
    function twice(int a) constant returns(int) {
        return 2*a;
    }
}
```

The above code was compiled and deployed with the following Javascript code:

```
var compiledSimple = web3.eth.compile.solidity(<source>);
var contractSimple = web3.eth.contract(<ABI>);

contractSimple.new( { from: <fromAddress>, data: compiledSimple, gas: "0x493e0" },
    function(err, contract) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
            return;
        }   
        if (!contract.address) {
            console.log('Address to be assigned... txnHash: ', contract.transactionHash);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Simple contract DEPLOYED at address: " + contract.address);
        }
    }
);
```

Now, I could call the function `twice(int)`, which returned the correct result i.e. the input integer doubled.

Then, I modified the code to the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract owned {
    address owner;
    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function getOwner() constant returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }
}

contract simple is owned {
    function twice(int a) constant returns(int) {
        return 2*a;
    }
}
```

After deploying this with the same Javascript code, I find that I can call `getOwner()` and get the correct `<fromAddress>` that was specified when contract was deployed. However, calling `twice(int)` always returns 0, whatever the input value may be. It looks as if only the base contract got deployed, and not the derived contract.

Here is the ABI specified when deploying the later code:

```
var ABI_SIMPLE = [ 
  {"constant":true,
   "inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"int256"}],
   "name":"twice",
   "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"int256"}],
   "payable":false,
   "type":"function"},
  {"constant":true,
   "inputs":[],
   "name":"getOwner",
   "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],
   "payable":false,
   "type":"function"}
];
```

Am I missing something here? Really appreciate any help.

**EDIT: Code calling the contract**

Here is the code that calls the contract function `twice(int)`. It is part of a NodeJS application, and `ABI_SIMPLE` (given above) and `ADDRESS_SIMPLE` are defined as constants outside the code block below. HTTP request has header `Content-Type: application/json`:

```
var invokeSimple = function(req, res) {
    var inVal = parseInt(req.params.input);
    var simple = web3.eth.contract(ABI_SIMPLE).at(ADDRESS_SIMPLE);
    var result = simple.twice(inVal);
    res.status(200).send({result: result});
}
```

Comment: How do you call the contract?

Comment: Added Javascript code calling the contract function.

Comment: Can you add a confirmation that your `inVal` is a correctly parsed integer. This code does not fully demonstrate what goes into the function, as it comes from an external source and the reader needs to guess.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, @MikkoOhtamaa . I have a `console.log` statement after reading inVal, which prints out correct integer value. I had taken it out to get the minimal code.

Comment: By presented all facts in this question, it should return the value 20. I suggest you deploy the contract on a public testnet so its testable there or try to add som other clues what's going on here. I suggest you try to publish on testnet so that the source code is verified on testnet.etherscan.io.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will try that. BTW, the `a` in `return 2*a` is the input argument, not 10 in hex format. Thought you might have interpreted that way because you said it should return the value 20. Just a side note.

Comment: This is a stupid idea, but try this first: Pass in string "0x10" instead of an integer.